# Does async/await have an extra cost associated when returning early from the method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Does async/await have an extra cost associated when returning early from the method compared to the synchronous method?

Take these examples:

```
public async Task<bool> TryDoSomethingAsync()
{
    if ( Is99PercentOfTheCases() )
        return false;  // does this path...

    await DoSomethingAsync();

    return true;
}

// versus 

public bool TryDoSomething()
{
    if ( Is99PercentOfTheCases() )
        return false; // ...have the same cost as this path?

    DoSomething();

    return true;
}
```

I know async/await has an extra cost associated and therefore you need to be careful around tight loops - see i.e. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-framework/the-overhead-of-asyncawait-in-net-4-5/

But when is this cost occurring?

- Is it when you mark a method as async?
- Is it when it needs to await?
- Or is it related to the Task return type?
- Especially: does the performance hit still occur when returning early for an async method?

In the end it's always best to profile specific cases, but I'm interested in the theory behind it.

Comment: That linked article, talking specifically about .NET 4.5, is woefully out of date -- there have been many improvements in the JIT since (especially in .NET Core, but also in the 4.6+ JIT RyuJIT branch), and of course there's `ValueTask`. These optimizations make talking about "the" cost of `async`/`await` quite complicated -- things are always moving in the direction of minimizing and/or eliminating overhead entirely, so that it is indeed dangerous to reason generally without profiling.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert, thanks for your answer! In conclusion - so I guess you're saying there *is* an extra cost in the path returning early? No matter how small or large.

Comment: The second `TryDoSomethingAsync` method has a deceptive name because it is not an asynchronous method. In 1% of the cases will block the current thread while doing something. So I have two questions to ask: for how long will the current thread be blocked in 1% of the cases, and if the current thread is a UI thread or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in your `TryDoSomethingAsync` get converted by the compiler to IL code that is, more or less, the equivalent of this:

```
public Task<bool> TryDoSomethingAsync()
{
    TryDoSomethingAsyncStateMachine stateMachine = new TryDoSomethingAsyncStateMachine();
    stateMachine._this = this;
    stateMachine._builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool>.Create();
    stateMachine._state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> _builder = stateMachine._builder;
    _builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine._builder.Task;
}

private sealed class TryDoSomethingAsyncStateMachine : IAsyncStateMachine
{
    public int _state;
    public AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<bool> _builder;
    public UserQuery _this;

    private TaskAwaiter _awaiter;

    private void MoveNext()
    {
        int num = _state;
        bool result;
        try
        {
            TaskAwaiter awaiter;
            if (num == 0)
            {
                awaiter = _awaiter;
                _awaiter = default(TaskAwaiter);
                num = (_state = -1);
                goto IL_0080;
            }
            if (!_this.Is99PercentOfTheCases())
            {
                awaiter = _this.DoSomethingAsync().GetAwaiter();
                if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
                {
                    num = (_state = 0);
                    _awaiter = awaiter;
                    TryDoSomethingAsyncStateMachine stateMachine = this;
                    _builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
                    return;
                }
                goto IL_0080;
            }
            result = false;
            goto end_IL_0007;
        IL_0080:
            awaiter.GetResult();
            result = true;
        end_IL_0007:;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _state = -2;
            _builder.SetException(exception);
            return;
        }
        _state = -2;
        _builder.SetResult(result);
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    private void SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
    }

    void IAsyncStateMachine.SetStateMachine(IAsyncStateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in SetStateMachine
        this.SetStateMachine(stateMachine);
    }
}
```

There is considerable more code that is run that the plain async method.

However, the code that runs the `Is99PercentOfTheCases()` is still fairly light. It will be quick, but not as quick as the non-async method.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity - thanks for your time for answering. Does this also mean that if you don't use async/await, but do return tasks that the statemachine is not being created and therefore you don't incur the cost?

Comment: You are correct Dirk, adding the `async` modifier on the function causes the state machine to be created. If you don't have the method marked `async` then there will be no state machine.